# [google-assistant-sdk]-Google Assistant demo

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to install Google Assistant SDK on raspberry Pi 3. I have followed all the steps which are mentioned on the developer page.Whenever I am trying to run 
**google-assistant-demo** command I am getting following error.

[image]

Comment: please, don't post screenshots of terminal output. Instead, just copy-paste it into a code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the argument like project id and device model id to run the model. Those ids can be found by the registered app on action.google.com.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this working on My Pi this morning.  I found that in the .asoundrc file in the /Home/pi folder had extra lines in it that was switching the configuration.  This caused the sample files to not run properly and gave me an error relating to permissions.  Once I fixed that it all worked fine.

I know you said that you followed the developers page. Just want to make sure that we used the same one.  It worked great for me. after I setup the security access on my google account.  https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/setup

I hope that helps, if not know that at least I tried.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. As this is one of your first answers I would like to suggest you to read [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for improving your future answers.

Comment: @Mike I have tried that but still getting the same error. Error : Google assistant demo error: Following arguments required : device_model_id

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you register a new device and then write down or copy to a text file the Device model ID. It appears when you run registration of a new device. [Link:](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/register-device)  I had the same problems i believe it is made up of parts of project id and product name. But i will run the setup again later this week and post my results if i get it to work.